# Youtube Iframe api, check when the user has moved the video?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have an embeded youtube player and i want to have like an event that fires when user moves the video to different time.

I think youtube player api is this:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#playVideo

and as far as i cant tell there is no method on that page that could do this.

again lets say video is playing and if users moves the video i want to know it.

Comment: i'm thinking only way might be just make my own slider and hide youtube controls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to listen to an event? Maybe another Play or Buffer event will be fired and you can compare to the previous state?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Adding_event_listener

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Comment: so there are statechange event which fires, but it just says playing/buffering/paused/stopped etc....

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Sorry, I am not at all familiar with this API. I presume the statechange function is passed an event and an object representing the new state. Try inspecting the event object for clues about what the previous state was, then deduce what action was taken. If was Playing and now Playing again, perhaps the user skipped to a different timestamp? Shot in the dark.